# Dynamic href link to Contact Page

Tags: pages, page-template, contact

I need a `<a href="Something Like <?get_contact_page>">Contact Page</a>` Code that always links to the Contact page, no matter what is it's ID

There's a page template for contact page.

Is it possible to do this?

I'll gladly provide any further information you need :)

Thanks!!

Comment: Lucas, please see: [How does accepting an answer works?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/185667)

Comment: I'm sorry, I've posted the question and slept!! I never fail to accept an answer and thank everyone who helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contact page is identified solely by the associated template, you can query for a page with the template name in meta key `_wp_page_template`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'value' => 'contact_template.php'
        )
    )
);
$contact_page = new WP_Query( $args );

if( ! empty( $contact_page->posts ) )
    echo get_permalink( $contact_page->post->ID );
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me! I pretty much provided the same code, except I created a function and account for instances where a template is assigned to more than one page and support returning an array or echoing single keyed values in the return array.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck. Wordpress stores a pages template value in a hidden custom field not visible in the backend but very much exists called, "_wp_page_template". I created the following function which should return an array or a single key of data for you.

[I put the code on Github Gist here](https://gist.github.com/Vheissu/5001244) because it's a little long. I did some testing and it seems to work! Should do what you want it too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `get_page_by_title()` that you might find useful:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title

If the title is always "`Contact Page`" then you can use

```
<?php $page = get_page_by_title("Contact Page");?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $page->ID ); ?>">Link to my Contact Page</a>
```

Comment: This won't work in the instance of a client website and they decide that the page which was called, "Contact Us" when the site was built would read better if it said, "Get in Contact" which would break this code. Good idea in theory, but you should never assume things will be constant (especially page titles).

Comment: I agree, I somehow missed the "template" sentence of his question ;-)

Comment: Happens to the best of us man! :)

Comment: your `get_page_by_template()` function looks very useful, nice.

Comment: Thanks man. It's probably a little rough around the edges, but seems to get the job done! I might go and clean it up a little later because it's a pretty useful function.